# I am trying to build a simple calculator in React using components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a simple calculator in React using components. I want to take the value of the button and assign it to "currentItem", however, I keep getting the error "Cannot read property 'setState' of null". Here is the code. The code is in 2 separate jsx files. I would really appreciate the help.

```
import React from 'react';
import NumbersComponent from './NumbersComponent.jsx';
import EquationComponent from './EquationComponent.jsx';
import FunctionComponent from './FunctionComponent.jsx';

require('../../stylesheets/component/CalculatorModule.scss');

export default class CalculatorModule extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentItem:"0"
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="calculatorWrapper">
                <div className="display">
                    <div>{this.state.currentItem}</div>
                </div>

                <section className="controlArea">
                    <FunctionComponent/>
                    <div>
                        <NumbersComponent/>
                        <EquationComponent/>
                    </div>
                </section>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

import React from 'react';

require('../../stylesheets/component/NumbersComponent.scss');

export default class NumbersComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="buttonBoxLeft">
                <button type="button" value="1" onClick={this.handleClick}>1</button>
                <button type="button" value="2" onClick={this.handleClick}>2</button>
                <button type="button" value="3" onClick={this.handleClick}>3</button>
                <button type="button" value="4" onClick={this.handleClick}>4</button>
                <button type="button" value="5" onClick={this.handleClick}>5</button>
                <button type="button" value="6" onClick={this.handleClick}>6</button>
                <button type="button" value="7" onClick={this.handleClick}>7</button>
                <button type="button" value="8" onClick={this.handleClick}>8</button>
                <button type="button" value="9" onClick={this.handleClick}>9</button>
                <div className="zeroSection">
                    <button value="0" id="zero">0</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    handleClick(){
        this.setState({
            currentItem: this.value
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using ES6, in which case you need to `bind` the `this` context to the event handler, otherwise `this` is undefined. In ES6, classes don't automatically `bind` this `this` context, you have to do it explicitly.

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

Or even better, do it in the constructor, which will `bind` it once for the entire component, which is [the recommended method.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#autobinding)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Edit: Looking again though, it looks like you're trying to get the `this` context of the clicked button so that you can grab its value. What you should do is move the "value" properties into the component state where they can be read and modified without issue. Don't store information in the DOM, store it explicitly in React state.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem. I am still new to coding. Could you explain what you meant by "What you should do is move the "value" properties into the component state where they can be read and modified without issue. Don't store information in the DOM, store it explicitly in React state."? I really would like to learn the proper way of coding in React.

Comment: @LonnieMcGill Have you read the official documentation as well as done the tutorial? In React, "state" is like a set of variables and conditions that are internal to a component. Information about how a component should render and behave is kept in "state" so that it can be easily read and modified. Data from "state" should flow into and be rendered as HTML DOM elements, not the other way around. This is a basic principle of React. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Thank you. I've learned most of React from tutorials. So i'll start reading the docs now. Once agin though thank you for answering so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the "this" context in your handleClick() function, which is not, as you think, the react component.

To keep 'this' as your react component, you can use arrow functions, like this:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        currentItem: this.value
    })
}
```

Note: I'm assuming you're using babel (and the [Class properties transform plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)) since you're using es6 class. But if it's not the case, manually bind "this", as previous answers suggest it, is a good option.